# iOS : Expandable list view not drawing newly added control

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to create an expandable list view in iOS using Xamarin with MvvmCross.

The scenario is that I have a listview, and when a row in the listview is selected, it expands (animates) to reveal a collection view, loaded in via lazyloading.

Here is the code I have so far:

**Adapter :**

```
public class MercatoAnimatedExpandableTableSource : MvxTableViewSource
{
    private readonly string _key;
    private readonly List<object> items;
    private Dictionary<object, bool> expandableState = new Dictionary<object, bool>(); 

    public MercatoAnimatedExpandableTableSource(UITableView tableView, IEnumerable<object> items, UINib nib, string key)
        : base(tableView)
    {
        _key = key;
        this.items = items.ToList();
        this.items.ForEach(x => expandableState[x] = true);
        tableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse(nib, key);
    }

    protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
    {
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(_key);

        cell.Frame = new RectangleF(cell.Frame.X, cell.Frame.Y, cell.Frame.Width, GetHeightForRow(tableView, indexPath));

        return cell;
    }

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        base.RowSelected(tableView, indexPath);

        var isExpanded = expandableState[items[indexPath.Row]];

        expandableState[items[indexPath.Row]] = !isExpanded;

        var row = this.GetCell(tableView, indexPath);

        (row as FamilysubgroupViewCell).ExpandCells();

        tableView.ReloadRows(new[] { indexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic); 
    }

    public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var isExpanded = expandableState[items[indexPath.Row]];
        if (isExpanded)
        {
            return 25;
        }

        return 400;
    }

    protected override object GetItemAt(NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return items[indexPath.Row];
    }
}
```

**Cell :**

```
    public FamilySubgroupViewCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        this.DelayBind(() =>
        {
            this.FamilyCollectionViewContainer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
            var bindingset = this.CreateBindingSet<FamilySubgroupViewCell, FamilySubTypeViewModel>();
            bindingset.Bind(this.FamilyGroupTitleLabel).To(x => x.FamilySubType.FamilySubGroupDescription);
            bindingset.Bind(this.FamilyGroupDescLabel).To(x => x.FamilySubType.FamilySubGroupDetail); 
            bindingset.Apply();
        });

    }

    public void ExpandCells(Action onUpdate)
    {
        var context = this.DataContext as FamilySubTypeViewModel;
        context.PopulateAndRun(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Populating Models complete : now showing cells");
            var collection = new FamilySubGroupModelsCollection();
            collection.ViewModel = context;
            Debug.WriteLine("FamilySubGroupCell : Showing {0} Items", context.FamilyModels.Count);

            this.FamilyCollectionViewContainer.Add(collection.View);

            if (onUpdate != null) onUpdate();
        });
    }
```

**Issue**

So when a cell is selected, it flips the 'isExpanded' property which gives it a new height - that works fine. The cell is then sent a message to 'expand' the cell, which in turn loads a new collection and adds it to the view (via View outlet).

However, the collection is never re-rendered on the view. It populates fine, adds to the view but it is never actually visible on the newly expanded cell. If i load it in when the cell is initially created in the DelayBind() method (ie - no lazy loading) then it works ok.

Have tried things like redrawing the cell

```
this.Draw(this.Bounds);
```

after the collection was added to the view, but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This block of code feels like it might be confusing your display:

```
    var row = this.GetCell(tableView, indexPath);
    (row as FamilysubgroupViewCell).ExpandCells();
    tableView.ReloadRows(new[] { indexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic);
```

What this does is:

- get the current cell and tell it to expand
- then ask the table to reload the row (at which point a different cell instance might be used).

I'd also worry that the line:

```
    var context = this.DataContext as FamilySubTypeViewModel;
```

would link your cells sub-display to the current viewmodel - and this wouldn't update if the cell were reused (given a new viewmodel).

One quick (and only slightly dirty) way around both of these problems would be to change the override for `GetOrCreateCellFor` to something like:

```
protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
{
    var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(_key);

    cell.Frame = new RectangleF(cell.Frame.X, cell.Frame.Y, cell.Frame.Width, GetHeightForRow(tableView, indexPath));

    ((MyCellType)cell).ShowExpandedState(expandableState[items[indexPath.Row]]);

    return cell;
}
```

Where `ShowExpandedState(bool)` would be capable of resetting the cell's expanded area after reuse.

---

Other options:

- Instead of this, you could simply return a different cell type for expanded versus non-expanded rows?
- Or you could put the expanded/non-expanded information in the Cell's ViewModel so that it can data-bind to that expanded state and update it's own layout? (you'd still need some mechanism to tell the table about the size change though)

---

On:

```
this.Draw(this.Bounds);
```

I'm not too surprised this didn't work - generally you have to encourage the system to redraw views - using things like `SetNeedsDisplay` (and sometimes after child changes `SetNeedsLayout` too)

Comment: You're spot on with your first observation. The    tableView.ReloadRows() was instantiating a new cell that didn't have the expanded collection view inside it. Placing the code you suggested in GetOrCreateCellFor did the trick. Thanks!